# How can I put an array in between two inputs

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn how I can I put names in between inputs.

If I input two random words and I want to put another word in between using array's how can I achieve that?

I'm still new to coding so if it isn't complicated code that would be amazing.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. Show some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please see the how to ask a good question FAQ (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your question should include your attempt at solving your problem, and include a specific issue that you are stuck on

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place.

> array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])

```js
const words = ["Hello", "world"];
words.splice(1, 0, " ");
console.log(words);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    //you can add elements to middle of  array using splice, there is more ways.
    const strings=['your','array','after','this']
     
    //go the index,remove 0 elements and then add 'In Here!' to it
    let index = (strings.length + 1) /2 
    strings.splice(index,0,'In Here!')

    console.log(strings)
```